# Javascript/JQuery to do rollover-effect confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, effect, rollover

So basically I'm doing some distance courses on Javascript with help of JQuery.
On one of the assignments it demands that:

- To do a image change
- That image change with a rollover-effect.

Because it's originatelly on swedish (I'm born in sweden and speak swedish) I get a bit confused cause every help of information I get on the internet on my programming is in english. Hope you understand..

```
$(document).ready(function (){

//bildbyte(attr) med rollover-effekt
$('#lamp').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'pic_bulbon.gif');
}); 
$('#lamp').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'pic_bulboff.gif');
});
});
```

Would it seem acceptable? Would you confirm it? I'm just a bit confused on the rollover effect.
The code will represent a lamp that isn't light up. But as soon you move your mouse over it goes on.

Opinions?

Comment: There is also hover function which does exactly what you want to do. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

Comment: Yeah I have used it before, but don't know why I used these two now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try using jQuery's [`hover()` function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). This would help make your code easier to read, and it might help you organize what happens when the bulb turns on/off. For example:

```
var bulbOn = function() { ... }

var bulbOff = function() { ... }

$('#lamp').hover(bulbOn, bulbOff);
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/84SQJ/) a jsfiddle to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got a catch o hover-function don't know why I used those two in the beginning, but as my code goes it works also.

Would you have accepted my code as the assignment demands it to?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback once again!